Input field is not showing character tails
I am having a problem creating my web page. I am using a downloaded font, which looks correct everywhere except in the input field.
The tails of the characters g, q, y, p, j do not show correctly in the input field, but they do in all other types of fields (divs, ul, p, for example).
I'm a bit confused and haven't found anything on the internet, just someone having a similar issue but with cuts on the left side (he fixed it with identation).
In the picture below you can read how my search bar (input field) cuts off the tails of the word "Dagger", while the search suggestion field ( tag)shows the word correctly.
If I change font, this stops happening. I have no padding or margin applied to either the input or the text.
This is my first post, so thank you very much in advance for any help.
Image

Please edit your question to include the relevant parts of your HTML and CSS code.

It certainly appears like there is padding in both the search bar and the search suggestion field. Why else would there be so much white space around the word "dagger"? Of course, we need to see your HTML and CSS in order to advise further. But if you swap to a different font and it works, it is likely to be a problem with the font itself. The font may be missing some metrics or have incorrect metrics specified. Choose a font from a reputable type foundry.

Please show what font this is.

Please provide code for a minimal reproducible example. Anyway, please check the line-height of this element. It might be too small and therefore cuts off the text.
